# Tagging friends not working while link sharing using Feed dialog

Tags: facebook-ios-sdk, sharing

I use FBWebDialogs  presentFeedDialogModallyWithSession:parameters:handler:
for sharing on facebook. 
I passed the parameter as

```
NSMutableDictionary *parameterDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
parameterDict[@"link"] =@"link url";
parameterDict[@"name"]=@"Hello world";
parameterDict[@"caption"]=@"caption string";
parameterDict[@"friends"] = fbfriends;
FBGraphObject *obj = places[0];    
parameterDict[@"place"]= [obj valueForKey:@"id"];
parameterDict[@"linkDescription"]= @"Just a test of sharing.";
```

Here link is posted on Facebook wall but tagging is not working
Any Idea folks?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the reference doc for feed dialog and associated parameters:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/v2.2

As you can see, there are no parameters named `friends`, `place`, or `linkDescription`. You cannot tag a friend or a place via the feed dialog, and you should change `linkDescription` to be just `description`.